# Submenu with aria-controls on responsive wordpress not closing on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have been trying to produce my second wordpress site and I am still at the testing stage, as I have produced this by doing an online course, but have pushed it further and added my own particular elements to it. I have been using localhost via mamp to do the testing as I don't have my own server to give you a link. I have looked through several forums online about the use of aria-controls and tried various things myself for the last few weeks and I have not found a solution at all to my problem.

The site works fine for mobile/tablet, but has a problem when I test it on the desktop version. I am unable to get the submenu to close when a menu item is selected. Clicking on another menu header works as expected. If anyone can offer any help that would very much be appreciated as I am still very much a beginner.

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

```js
( function( $ ) {
 var container, button, menu, links, subMenus;

 container = document.getElementById( 'site-navigation' );
 if ( ! container ) {
  return;
 }

 button = container.getElementsByTagName( 'button' )[0];
 if ( 'undefined' === typeof button ) {
  return;
 }

 menu = container.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' )[0];

 // Hide menu toggle button if menu is empty and return early.
 if ( 'undefined' === typeof menu ) {
  button.style.display = 'none';
  return;
 }

 menu.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
 if ( -1 === menu.className.indexOf( 'nav-menu' ) ) {
  menu.className += ' nav-menu';
 }

 button.onclick = function() {
  if ( -1 !== container.className.indexOf( 'toggled' ) ) {
   container.className = container.className.replace( ' toggled', '' );
   button.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
   menu.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
  } else {
   container.className += ' toggled';
   button.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
   menu.setAttribute( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
  }
 };

 // Get all the link elements within the menu.
 links    = menu.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );
 subMenus = menu.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' );

 // Set menu items with submenus to aria-haspopup="true".
 for ( var i = 0, len = subMenus.length; i < len; i++ ) {
  subMenus[i].parentNode.setAttribute( 'aria-haspopup', 'true' );
 }

 // Each time a menu link is focused or blurred, toggle focus.
 for ( i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++ ) {
  links[i].addEventListener( 'focus', toggleFocus, true );
  links[i].addEventListener( 'blur', toggleFocus, true );
 }

 /**
  * Sets or removes .focus class on an element.
  */
 function toggleFocus() {
  var self = this;

  // Move up through the ancestors of the current link until we hit .nav-menu.
  while ( -1 === self.className.indexOf( 'nav-menu' ) ) {

   // On li elements toggle the class .focus.
   if ( 'li' === self.tagName.toLowerCase() ) {
    if ( -1 !== self.className.indexOf( 'focus' ) ) {
     self.className = self.className.replace( ' focus', '' );
    } else {
     self.className += ' focus';
    }
   }

   self = self.parentElement;
  }
 }

 function initMainNavigation( container ) {
  // Add dropdown toggle that display child menu items.
  container.find( '.menu-item-has-children > a, .page_item_has_children > a' ).after( '<button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">' + screenReaderText.expand + '</button>' );

  // Toggle buttons and submenu items with active children menu items.
  container.find( '.current-menu-ancestor > button' ).addClass( 'toggle-on' );
  container.find( '.current-menu-ancestor > .sub-menu' ).addClass( 'toggled-on' );

  container.find( '.dropdown-toggle' ).click( function( e ) {
   var _this = $( this );
   e.preventDefault();
   _this.toggleClass( 'toggle-on' );
   _this.next( '.children, .sub-menu' ).toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );
   _this.attr( 'aria-expanded', _this.attr( 'aria-expanded' ) === 'false' ? 'true' : 'false' );
   _this.html( _this.html() === screenReaderText.expand ? screenReaderText.collapse : screenReaderText.expand );
  } );
 }
 initMainNavigation( $( '.main-navigation' ) );

 // Re-initialize the main navigation when it is updated, persisting any existing submenu expanded states.
 $( document ).on( 'customize-preview-menu-refreshed', function( e, params ) {
  if ( 'primary' === params.wpNavMenuArgs.theme_location ) {
   initMainNavigation( params.newContainer );

   // Re-sync expanded states from oldContainer.
   params.oldContainer.find( '.dropdown-toggle.toggle-on' ).each(function() {
    var containerId = $( this ).parent().prop( 'id' );
    $( params.newContainer ).find( '#' + containerId + ' > .dropdown-toggle' ).triggerHandler( 'click' );
   });
  }
 });

 // Hide/show toggle button on scroll

 var position, direction, previous;

 $(window).scroll(function(){
  if( $(this).scrollTop() >= position ){
   direction = 'down';
   if(direction !== previous){
    $('.menu-toggle').addClass('hide');

    previous = direction;
   }
  } else {
   direction = 'up';
   if(direction !== previous){
    $('.menu-toggle').removeClass('hide');

    previous = direction;
   }
  }
  position = $(this).scrollTop();
 });

 // Wrap centered images in a new figure element
 $( 'img.aligncenter' ).wrap( '<figure class="centered-image"></figure>');

} )( jQuery );
```

```css
.main-navigation {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1em;
 }
 
 .main-navigation ul {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 6em;
    margin-bottom: 3em; 
 }
 
 .main-navigation li {
  position: relative;
 }
 
 .main-navigation ul ul {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 0.8em;
 }
 
.main-navigation a {
  /*z-index: 300; */
    position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.8em 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  color: white;
 } 

.main-navigation a:hover,
.main-navigation a:focus {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;*/
    background-color: transparent; 
    border-bottom: none; 
 }


.main-navigation a, 
.main-navigation ul ul li:last-child a {
   border-bottom: 1px solid white;
   background: transparent;
   color: #fff;
} 

.main-navigation ul li:last-child a {
 border-bottom: none;
}

.main-navigation ul .toggled-on {
  display: block;
 } 

.main-navigation li { /* bottom menu buttom */
  border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.1);
  position: relative;
 } 

 .main-navigation .current-menu-item > a,
 .main-navigation .current-menu-ancestor > a,
 .main-navigation .current_page_item > a,
 .main-navigation .current_page_ancestor > a {
  font-weight: 700;
 }
 
 .main-navigation .nav-menu > ul > li:first-child,
 .main-navigation .nav-menu > li:first-child {
  border-top: 0;
 }
 
 .main-navigation .menu-item-has-children > a,
 .main-navigation .page_item_has_children > a{
  padding-right: 48px;
 }
 
 .no-js .main-navigation ul ul {
  display: block;
 }
 
 .dropdown-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 27px;
  width: 27px;
  top: 12px;
  right: 6px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  background-color: #045F66;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  content: "";
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: lowercase; /* Stop screen readers from reading the text as capital letters */
 } 

.dropdown-toggle:after {
  content: "\f078";
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 27px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 1px;
  width: 27px;
 }
 
 .dropdown-toggle:hover,
 .dropdown-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #045F66;
 }
 
 .dropdown-toggle.toggle-on:after {
  content: "\f077";
 }

 /* Small menu. */
 .menu-toggle,
 .main-navigation.toggled ul {
  display: block;
 }
 
 .menu-toggle {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 300;
  bottom: 1em;
  left: 1em;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #00A3B9;
  color: #fff;
  border: solid 2px #fff;
  transition: all ease-out 400ms;
 }
 
 .menu-toggle.hide {
  bottom: -2.5em;
 }
 
 /*Make sure the button doesn't hide when menu is open. */
 
 .toggled .menu-toggle.hide {
  bottom: 1em;
 }
 
 
 .menu-toggle:hover,
 .menu-toggle:focus {
  text-decoration: underline;
 }
 
 @media screen and (min-width: 50em) {
  .menu-toggle {
   display: none;
  }
  .main-navigation ul {
   display: block;
  }
 }
 
 /* Hovering menu */
 
 .main-navigation.toggled {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  z-index: 1;
 }
 
 .nav-menu {
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  /*background-color: #045F66;*/
    background-color: #a8b8a5;
 }
 
 .main-navigation.toggled ul {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 8em);
  overflow-y: auto;
 }
 
 .main-navigation.toggled ul ul {
  display: none;
 }
 
 .main-navigation.toggled ul ul.toggled-on,
 .main-navigation.toggled ul ul.toggled-on > ul {
  display: block;
 }
 
 /* Horizontal menu on wide screens */
 @media screen and (min-width: 50em) {
  .menu-toggle. {
   display: none;
  }
  /* Position the menu in the header */
  .main-navigation,
  .main-navigation.toggled {
   position: relative;
   min-height: 3em;
   max-width: 150em;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 0 4em;
   background-color: #045F66;
   background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .7);
  }
  
  .nav-menu {
   padding: 0.5em 0 0 0.5em;
   background-color: transparent;
  }
  
  .main-navigation ul,
  .main-navigation.toggled ul {
   max-height: none;
   padding-left: 0;
   text-align: center;
  }
  
  .main-navigation.toggled ul {
   overflow-y: hidden;
  }
  
  /* Display the menu items in a horizontal order */
  .main-navigation li {
   display: inline-block;
   border: none;
  }
  
  /* Add an outline to the drop-down menus */
  .main-navigation ul ul {
   outline: 1px solid #333;
  }
  
  /* Left-align drop-down menu items */
  .main-navigation li li {
   display: block;
   text-align: left;
        background-color: #a8b8a5;
  }
  
  .main-navigation a,
  .main-navigation ul ul li:last-child a {
   border-bottom: none;
  }
  
  /* Add an outline on hovered and focused menu items */
  .main-navigation a:hover,
  .main-navigation a:focus {
   background: transparent;
   color: #fff;
   text-decoration: underline;
   outline: solid 1px #b3b3b3;
  }
  
  /* Create hover and focus contrast on drop-down items */
  .main-navigation li li a:hover,
  .main-navigation li li a:focus {
   background: #eee;
   color: #000;
   text-decoration: none;
  }
  
 /* Position drop-down menus absolutely */
  .main-navigation ul ul.toggled-on {
   position: absolute;
   width: 10em;
   display: block;
   z-index: 10;
   margin-left: 0;
   background: #000;
  }
  
  .main-navigation ul ul ul.toggled-on {
   position: relative;
  }
  
  /* Indent 3rd level drop-down menus */
  .main-navigation ul ul ul a {
   padding-left: 2em;
  }
  
  /* Simplify the drop-down toggle */
  .dropdown-toggle {
   top: 11px;
   right: 12px;
   border: none;
  }
  
  .dropdown-toggle::after {
   line-height: 27px;
   width: 27px;
  }
  
 }
```

```html
  <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
 <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false">Menu</button>
 <div class="menu-main-container"><ul id="primary-menu" class="nav-menu"><li id="menu-item-199" class="home menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-197 current_page_item menu-item-199"><a title="Home" href="http://localhost:8888/plainly/">Home page</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-88" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-88"><a title="About" href="http://localhost:8888/plainly/?page_id=86">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1985" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1985"><a href="http://localhost:8888/plainly/?page_id=1962">Boats</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-1988" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1988"><a href="http://localhost:8888/plainly/?page_id=15">Rubix (IOM)</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-2014" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2014"><a href="http://localhost:8888/plainly/?page_id=2011">RG65</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-2015" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2015"><a href="http://localhost:8888/plainly/?page_id=2008">One meter</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-2016" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2016"><a href="http://localhost:8888/plainly/?page_id=2005">Ten rater</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-2017" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2017"><a href="http://localhost:8888/plainly/?page_id=2002">Vane boats</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-2018" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2018"><a href="http://localhost:8888/plainly/?page_id=1999">Six meter</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-2019" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2019"><a href="http://localhost:8888/plainly/?page_id=1996">A-Boats</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-1960" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1960"><a href="http://localhost:8888/plainly/?page_id=1953">Terms &#038; Conditions</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

Comment: Can you include the rendered HTML for the `nav`, not the PHP code? If you view source on your page, you should see all of the HTML in `nav`, and not PHP. Just put that in the code window here on SO instead of the PHP.

Comment: I have now added the HTML from the viewed source as you have suggested and replaced my existing PHP. Thanks for any help you may be able to offer.

Comment: What do you  mean "I am unable to get the submenu to close when a menu item is selected."? When I put your code in codepen, no submenus open in the desktop view. Your code doesn't work, either, and you should include everything needed to make a complete, verifiable example. It would be great if you could get your code window working instead of it throwing an error that jquery doesn't exist. Also your HTML is incomplete. It starts with a closing tag (</div), <nav> isn't closed anywhere, and there is a closing </header> tag but no opening <header> tag.

Answer (score 1):

Comment out the following block and it should work:

```
// Toggle buttons and submenu items with active children menu items.
container.find( '.current-menu-ancestor > button' ).addClass( 'toggle-on' );
container.find( '.current-menu-ancestor > .sub-menu' ).addClass( 'toggled-on' );
```

Comment: I have adjusted the above HTML and looked at what the wordpress generates from its PHP and because it is refactored into may sub files, I cannot really supply all the necessary code. That's what makes it difficult to test when you are only doing it locally. The part named "<ul class="sub-menu">" in the html is the submenu section which is a drop down menu of the main navigation header. On-click of a submenu item from the dropdown, your selected html page comes up in the browser for you to read, but the submenu just hangs open when it should have closed. Works for mobile, but not desktop view.

Comment: Thanks user3295482 it does now work, because I am using MAMP and I do nearly all my testing in Chrome and then if it works in that I then test it in other browsers. However, I had a thought about saving the pages as html and then loading them into other browsers and they all worked in Safari, Firefox, but not Chrome. There appears to be a bug with aria controls when using Chrome, does anyone know a work around for this? Chrome does not come up with any problems or issues when I view any elements on the console. I have also adapted the above Javascript, thanks to user3295482.

Comment: Chrome now does work with aria controls, it appears to be a browser extension which caused the issue after further investigation. Thanks for everyone contributions to helping me.